# JavaScript replace all the vowels in a string toUpperCase?

Tags: javascript, regex

Again new to JavaScript and coming over from Ruby/Python so I feel like `JS` is a smack in the face but yet I'm committed to mastering it. I want to replace all of the `vowels` to `vowels.toUpperCase()`.

**Example 1** 
I tried with `map` but I couldn't understand how to pass the index of the current iteration:

```
function vowelToUpCase(idx){
    if(vowel.test(new_arr[idx])) {
        new_arr[idx] = new_arr[idx].toUpperCase();
    }
}

new_arr.map(vowelToUpCase(idx));
new_arr.join('');
```

**Example 2** 
Anyway I figured this can be easily done on a `str` with some simple `regex`, well I figured wrong because I'm stuck with what you see below.

```
var new_arr = [ 'e', 'i', 'f', 'm', 'e', 'm', 'p', '*', '3' ];
var vowel = /[aeiou]/gi;
var str = new_arr.join('');
console.log(str);

str.replace(/([aeiou])/gi, function (match) { 
    var str = match.toUpperCase();
    console.log(str);
});
console.log(str);
```

Output:

```
eifmemp*3
E
I
E
eifmemp*3
```

Desired Output:

```
EIfmEmp*3
```

**Questions:**

1. Can you pass an index to the `map()` function?
2. What's wrong with my `str.replace` example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your map question:

```
var new_arr = [ 'e', 'i', 'f', 'm', 'e', 'm', 'p', '*', '3' ];

function vowelToUpCase(value, index, originalArray) {
    if(/[aeiou]/.test(value)) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
    }
    return value;
}

var fixed = new_arr.map(vowelToUpCase); // adding params here is bad
console.log(fixed.join(""));
```

Comment: Inside of `map` function you're passing in value, index, orginalArray,  but you call new_arr.map(vowelToUpCase) without any parameters. Where value, index, orginalArray instantiated?

Comment: The passing of those three parameters (in that order) is handled automatically by the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Here js doc from mozilla `arr.map(callback[, thisArg])` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map So those 3 params are part of the callback what is the `[, thisArg]` param. Am I understanding these docs correctly?

Comment: Good example of use of thisArg [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679976%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) (second example).  If the callback you provide is part of an object, and uses the `this` keyword to reference itself, you have to provide a reference to the instance via thisArg.

Answer (score 4):

**Two fundamental problems:**

1. [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't replace the string, it returns a new value (so we need to do `str = str.replace();`
2. Replace's callback function expects a returned value to successfully replace.

**Final code:**

```
str = str.replace(/([aeiou])/g, function (match) { 
    return match.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(str);
// EIfmEmp*3
```

**Note:** I removed the `i` modifier from the regex, since any captial letters will already be uppercase.  This will save performance on a *very* minor scale (since we won't run `E.toUpperCase();` since it is already uppercase).

---

To address @mplungjan's comment, no..regex can't really do any logic in a replace.  It can reference things and replace matches with static content.  Any modification of matches needs to be done with a callback function in your language of choice, though.  We can do 5 separate replace calls:

```
str = str.replace(/a/g, 'A');
str = str.replace(/e/g, 'E');
str = str.replace(/i/g, 'I');
str = str.replace(/o/g, 'O');
str = str.replace(/u/g, 'U');

console.log(str);
// EIfmEmp*3
```

While the [5 simple replacements](http://jsfiddle.net/8JePf/1/) is faster, I prefer code readability ;)

Comment: Do we even NEED a function? Can't we change [aeuou] to [AEIOU] with a simpler replace?

Comment: @Sam the "simple replace" solution is wrong because it will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum facepalm! I've been doing too much PHP, updated..surprisingly with it being 5 expressions, it still is faster without the callback

Comment: I see, I basically had the right answer... I'm annoyed that I can write this in 1 line of ruby code. My issue was thinking that `return` was a) optional and b) would break the block so I didn't attempt to use it.. It appears return in JS is much different than return in Ruby.. Oh well, off I go to learn more. Thanks.

Comment: We could chain them at least

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/sjnEp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Include the code in your answer in case CodePen goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of a custom filter.

```
var array = [ 'e', 'i', 'f', 'm', 'e', 'm', 'p', '3','h','e','l','l','o'];
var result = []
array.forEach(function (e) {
  /[aeiouAEIOU]/.test(e) ? '' : result.push(e);
})
console.log(result)
```