# Vowels letters in upper case

Tags: javascript

Morning guys!

I need the vowels letters in upper case.

I've tried this but doesn't work:

```
let arr = ['1 abcde', '2 abcde', '3 abcde'];
let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
let list = [];

for(let item in arr){
    if(item in vogals){
    list.push(item.toUpperCase());
    }else{
    list.push(item.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

I want this result:

```
//Expected result: 
arr = ['1 AbCdE', '2 AbCdE', '3 AbCdE']
```

Help me please!

Comment: That's not your actual code, presumably. Please post the actual code. And explain what error(s) you are seeing.

Comment: `if(item in vogals){` - What is `vogals`? Did you mean `vowels`?

Comment: and [JavaScript replace all the vowels in a string toUpperCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961434/javascript-replace-all-the-vowels-in-a-string-touppercase)

Comment: `if(item in vogals)`  Lets assume the first item `if ('1 abcde' in vowels)`  No, that's not going to work.

Comment: You have an incredible amount of errors. You may find it beneficial to review the fundamentals again first.

Comment: yes, I'm brazilian and I fogot to replace 'vogals' to 'vowels' sry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be probably something like this:

```js
let arr = ['1 abcde', '2 abcde', '3 abcde'];
let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
const result = arr.map(str => [...str].map(char => vowels.includes(char) ? char.toUpperCase() : char).join(''))
console.log(result)
```